# Android IP address issues - IP's do not match

Tags: android, arduino, ip, esp8266

I am trying to connect to the ESP8266 Wi-Fi module via android. I can do this no problem if I specify the module's IP address *(192.168.4.1)* and port number *(5050)*. I wanted however to be able to not specify the module's address and be able to retrieve it from `wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress()` given that I'm connected to the network. When doing so the IP retrieved is *192.168.4.115* and it seems to increment every time I try again; *192.168.4.116*, *192.168.4.117* and so on.

I was expecting the ip returned to be 192.168.4.1, any ideas why I'm getting these other addresses instead?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what are you doing, but this works for me very well.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wifiInfo.getIpAddress());
```

Don't forget to add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: omainegra, that is exactly what i am doing but in doing so the ip returned to me is 192.168.4.115 or 192.168.4.116, 192.168.4.117 etc. The ip of the ESP8266 is 192.168.4.1. When i use ip 192.168.4.1 to connect it works perfect but when i use 192.168.4.115 it fails... I hope that's clearer

Comment: @TexMex If you are using DHCP to obtain IP change it for an static IP address and check again